# How to insert a record into Microsoft Access using MFC?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, mfc

How can I insert record in Microsoft Access?

> ```
> CString SqlString;
> CString name="I want to add this variable in Table3";
> SqlString = "INSERT INTO Table3 (Name,Numbers) VALUES (name,099)";
> ```

When I do it that way gives the following error:

> Database error:Too few parameters.Expected 1.

Comment: What about some real code? this is not even correct syntax.

Comment: What is the correct syntax ? I just want to add input from the user in ms acces table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As @Federico noted, the syntax of the code you present here is obviously wrong (mismatching opening/closing parentheses and quotes), I guess it doesn't even compile, let alone run correctly. Is this the actual one? Did you test your SQL in MS-Access (Query Design), to see if it really works?

Comment: For starters `CString name='I want to add this variable in Table3';` -> `CString name = "I want to add this variable in Table3";`

Comment: I pasted an example code, but I just want to know how to add variable in sql/ms acces table?

Comment: I have provided an answer, but your code is incomplete. You don't even show how you are actually committing the update to the database. So I have tried to cover all bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a snippet from my own application:

```
BOOL CCommunityTalksApp::SetRecordForTalkNumber(int iTalkNumber, UINT uID, CString &rStrError)
{
    CDatabase   *pDatabase;
    CString     strSQL, strField;
    BOOL        bOK;

    pDatabase = theApp.GetDatabase();
    if(pDatabase != nullptr)
    {
        if (iTalkNumber == 9999)
            strField = _T(" ");
        else
            strField.LoadString(uID);
        strSQL.Format(_T("INSERT INTO [Public Talk Titles] ([Theme], [Category], [Talk Number]) VALUES ('%s', 'NS', %d)"), strField, iTalkNumber);

        TRY
        {
            pDatabase->ExecuteSQL((LPCTSTR)strSQL);
            bOK = TRUE;
        }
        CATCH(CDBException, Except)
        {
            rStrError = Except->m_strError;
            bOK = FALSE;
        }
        END_CATCH
    }

    return bOK;
}
```

As you can see:

1. Use `[` and `]` to wrap the table and field names to address any issues with spaces.
2. Qualify the field names first — particularly if you are only populating certain field values.
3. Wrap the **string** values with **single quotes**.

So:

`SqlString = "INSERT INTO Table3 (Name,Numbers) VALUES (name,099)";`

Would be something like:

`SqlString = "INSERT INTO [Table3] ([Name],[Numbers]) VALUES ('name',099)";`

I appreciate that the square brackets are not needed for your table / field names though.